# Do .NET XSL-FO document template designer controls exist?

Tags: .net, document

I'm currently investigating whether any .NET controls exist where I can design a document and generate an XSL-FO template from it?

I've seen syntax editors, but I'd rather have a drag and drop designer that anyone can use.

Comment: I don't know if any desingerfor .NET exists, but it seems the XSL-FO is not as powerful in .NET as it is, for example, in Java.  There are number of commercial ones and only one free (that I know - NFOP).  
OUt of curiosity, what XSL-FO processor are you using/planning to?

Comment: I don't think there is (as there are only a few applications around having such a feature like Altova StyleVision or Stylus Studio). Maybe you can figure out whether it is possible to host one of these apps in your own app, but that means your users will have to have an Altova or Stylus Studio license.

Comment: We are investigating XSL-FO processors to at the moment, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: We have used XmlPdf. Works great for us.

Comment: I have used NFOP. For my purpose it was fine, but I don't like ite depends on J# Redist. Seems to be only one free XSL-FO processor for .NET.

Comment: There is another free XSL-FO processor for .NET called FO.NET:
http://www.codeplex.com/fonet

I'm using it and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Digiforms Document Designer is currently mainained for both Win32 and .NET

However - Working with documents have more aspcts to it than just the creation.
Check out www.digiforms.com for more info. ( Revision control, access policies etc.)